# Convert list(x, y, z) to terra raster object

Tags: raster, r, terra

What's the easiest way to create a `terra` raster object from a list of cell coordinates for X and Y and a matrix of values?

Here's a sample list:

```
m = list(x=c(10,12,14,16), y=c(9, 12, 15), z=matrix(1:12, 4, 3))
```

The `raster` package handles this object and creates a raster

```
library(raster)
# Loading required package: sp
rm = raster(m)
rm
# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 3, 4, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 2, 3  (x, y)
# extent     : 9, 17, 7.5, 16.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : 1, 12  (min, max)
```

Note how it gets the extent from the coordinates by adding half a cell-width either side, although my list specified cell centres (because there was the same number of values in X and Y as the matrix dimension)

But `terra::rast` doesn't do this:

```
library(terra)
# terra 1.6.18
tm = rast(m)
# Error: [rast,list] none of the elements of x are a SpatRaster
```

I've looked at the functions in `terra` but can't find a simple way to do it. I could code this up and handle the extents and cell widths and make sure I transpose and flip the matrix if needed etc but I feel there should be a simple way already done. Is there?

And no, I'd rather not do: `terra::rast(raster::raster(listobject))`...

Answer (score 5):

Well, this is a very unsatisfactory answer but it may be a place to start. It looks like the "list" method for `terra::rast` is now only relevant for lists containing SpatRaster class objects and not xyz elements. So, in fact, this method no longer exist which necessitates brute force following the original raster list method.

I believe that this question merits an enhancement request be submitted to the [terra development site](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues). Hopefully the developer will chime in here with a simpler approach or expand the currently available list method to include xyz support.

```
library(terra)
library(raster)
m = list(x=c(10,12,14,16), y=c(9, 12, 15), z=matrix(1:12, 4, 3))
```

Here is paraphrased code lifted from the `raster::raster` function for the  list method.

```
  resx <- ( m$x[length(m$x)] - m$x[1] ) / (length(m$x)-1)
  resy <- ( m$y[length(m$y)] - m$y[1] ) / (length(m$y)-1)
    xmn <- min(m$x) - 0.5 * resx
    xmx <- max(m$x) + 0.5 * resx
    ymn <- min(m$y) - 0.5 * resy
    ymx <- max(m$y) + 0.5 * resy
  z <- t(m$z)
  z <- z[nrow(z):1, ]
```

There are then two ways it can be applied to create a SpatRaster object; as method "missing" using an extent object then piping the matrix to the raster or as "matrix" with a defined extent.

```
r1 <- rast(ext(xmn, xmx, ymn, ymx), resolution=c(resx, resy))
  r1[] <- as.numeric(z)
  
r2 <- rast(z, extent=c(xmn, xmx, ymn, ymx))
```

Verify resulting rasters against results from `raster::raster`

```
( r <- raster::raster(m) ) 
c(r1, r2) 

as.matrix(r)
matrix(r1[][,1],nrow=nrow(r1),ncol=ncol(r1))  
matrix(r2[][,1],nrow=nrow(r2),ncol=ncol(r2))
```